# Will using a micro SD & adapter instead of a normal SD card affect the quality of pictures and video?

Tags: sdhc, sdcard

I've just bought a 32GB Class 4 SD card from a seller on eBay and he has sent me a micro SD card of the same size and speed instead. Obviously I'm not too happy about this but we are going to Disney Land Paris in two days and I don't think I'll have time to exchange it.

I was wondering if using a micro SD card will affect the quality of pictures and video with my Fujitus Finepix S1850 at all?

Comment: I think someone who can should edit this question, or the title, since they are asking opposite things at present. It makes the accepted answer confusing.

Comment: It now makes sense - the title reflects the question - but the answers below don't address it!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: no. Your Fujitsu point and shoot camera has a much lower throughput than your card's max, so the bottleneck with shooting lots of pictures very, very quickly will be the camera itself, not the memory card. Additionally, there will be absolutely no difference in image of video quality... this is digital after all.

Comment: It was the write speed that I was worrying about, e.g. if recording video requires that it write to the SD card at 3Mb/s and the SD card maxes out at 2Mb/s then that would be an issue. Testing it now tho and it seems to be a genuine class 4 one.

Answer (score 8):

In my camera, that's what I have, and I have no problems.

At worst, your transfer speeds may be slower. But it will most definitely **not** affect the images captured.

Comment: Regular-to-Micro SD adapters don't contain anything other than enough metal to bring the contacts on the Micro card out to where the full-sized contacts should be.  Nothing electrical happens inside, so the card will run as a fast as it can.

Comment: Yours is the only relevant answer, as far as I can tell!